# Temple Run Breakdown

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This question is about understanding how a game like temple run might be implemented in HTML with/without using the `canvas`. I have a vague idea about how `swipeLeft`, `swipeRight`
etc. might be implemented. But I am not able to gauge how the environments might be developed.

I am not asking for any help with the code here .I just want to have your opinions about implementing the environment. Is it just one huge sprite? If so, how will the user see random environments in the game each time he spawns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a single sprite. Assuming we're talking about the same Temple Run, it's a 3D game, probably using OpenGL. The fog effect means the game doesn't have to render objects in the distance. If you want to make a similar game, I suggest you look at one of the fine 3D game platforms available for Android and/or iOS.

You can do 3D games in HTML, and there are libraries that help, but unless you're making a website and not a mobile app, then it's better to do it native.

Comment: Yes, I could go for native apps development.But the problem is the requirement of the game is to build a browser based game in HTML which can run on iPhone and android based devices.
Can you guys give me a few pointers about the libraries which I might need to use.I am not much experienced in HTML game development.

Comment: In that case, I recommend a 3D HTML engine like http://www.ambiera.com/copperlicht/ or http://cloudmach.com/ .